Speech-to-Text - chirp model sometimes returns empty transcription
I'm trying to get a transcription from audio with the "chirp" model using node.js Google.Cloud.Speech.V2 library.
I need to use the "chirp" model because I need transcription with punctuation in Polish, Hebrew, Malay, and some other languages, and "chirp" is the only supported model.
When trying to send a short audio file in Hebrew, GCP returned an empty transcription. Generally, sometimes it returns the correct transcription for some audio files, and sometimes an empty result.
Moreover, I sent the same request several times (using the same audio file and the same configuration), and on the 3rd or 4th time, I received the transcription.
Please note that this happens not only with Hebrew but with other languages ​​as well. I have seen it happen with Malay and Hungarian.
Audio file example - I'm pretty sure if you submit a request using this audio recording 3-4 times you will get a transcript.
Request configuration:

import { v2 as speechV2 } from '@google-cloud/speech'

const client = new speechV2.SpeechClient({
  apiEndpoint: 'us-central1-speech.googleapis.com',
})

const recognizeRequestConfig = {
  recognizer: 'projects/<PROJECT_ID>/locations/us-central1/recognizers/_',
  config: {
    features: { enableWordTimeOffsets: true, enableAutomaticPunctuation: true },
    autoDecodingConfig: {},
    languageCodes: [ 'iw-IL' ],
    model: 'chirp'
  },
  uri: 'gs://<URL>/audio/<ID>.webm'
}

const [recognizeResponse] = await client.recognize(recognizeRequestConfig)

Response:
{
  recognizeResponse: {
    results: [
      {
        alternatives: [ { words: [], transcript: '', confidence: 0 } ],
        channelTag: 0,
        resultEndOffset: { seconds: '1', nanos: 0 },
        languageCode: 'iw-IL'
      }
    ],
    metadata: { totalBilledDuration: { seconds: '2', nanos: 0 } }
  }
}


Hi @Mykyta Manuilenko, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support Case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue trackerdescribing your issue
